# Is it possible to make a nested Search API query?

Tags: search

I need to make a query in the following form:

```
SELECT * FROM {index}
...
AND (
  (field1 = value AND field2 = value) OR
  (field1 = other_value AND field2 = other_value)
)
...
```

But it doesn’t seem to be possible with the existing [createFilter](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!search_api!includes!query.inc/function/SearchApiQuery%3a%3acreateFilter/7) and [condition](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!search_api!includes!query.inc/function/SearchApiQueryFilterInterface%3a%3acondition/7) methods, as there is no way to pass another filter to a condition for example. Am I missing something, or is this (basic functionality?) really not there?

Comment: [Use createFilter to build an advanced query using AND and OR with the search API][1]


  [1]: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30294/use-createfilter-to-build-an-advanced-query-using-and-and-or-with-the-search-api

Answer (score 5):

The AND ((field1 = value AND field2 = value) OR (field1 = other_value AND field2 = other_Value)) IS possible with sub-filters. For anyone else who ends up here trying to sort this out (as I did before working out the correct solution) you can create the above like this:

```
$filter = $query->createFilter('OR');

$subfilter1 = $query->createFilter('AND');
$subfilter1->condition('field1',value);
$subfilter1->condition('field2',value);

// Add this subfilter to the main filter.
$filter->filter($subfilter1);

$subfilter2 = $query->createFilter('AND');
$subfilter2->condition('field1',other_value);
$subfilter2->condition('field2',other_value);

// Now add the second subfilter
$filter->filter($subfilter2);

// Apply the filter to the query.
$query->filter($filter);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean from UX, then it not has been implemented yet as the code states (file `search_api/includes/query.inc`):

```
// @todo Add fourth mode for complicated expressions, e.g.:
// "vanilla ice" OR (love NOT hate)
```

See: [Parse mode for complicated/complex expressions](https://drupal.org/node/1616734)

This should be implemented soon [in Drupal 8](https://drupal.org/node/2064637).

If you mean programatically, you can write your own filter, as [suggested](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30294/use-createfilter-to-build-an-advanced-query-using-and-and-or-with-the-search-api).

Or by installing Apache Solr and using [Search API Solr](http://drupal.org/project/search_api_solr) instead.